# Training time of Tensorflow Object Detection API on MSCOCO

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

How long does it typically take to train a Faster RCNN  model on MSCOCO on a single GPU card (e.g. K40 or 1080) using the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection)? It would be great if you could provide training times for other models (SSD and R-FCN), too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never trained a model on COCO using a single GPU --- we typically train using ~10 k40 GPUs with asynchronous SGD, which takes 3-4 days to converge on COCO.  SSD and R-FCN take about the same amount of time.

Comment: How long do you think SSD/Faster-RCNN will take with single Tesla P100? The dataset I am using is custom, has 34 classes and 70k object images. Any rough idea about time or number of iterations? 400k? 1m? 10m?